# MS Teams MessageCard cutting off long text messages instead of wrapping

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

I am setting up the JSON for my MS teams webhook like this:

```
String jsonMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject
                (
                    new
                    {
                        @type = "MessageCard",
                        themeColor = "d70000",
                        summary = "Error",
                        sections = new[] {
                            new {
                                activityTitle = "Error",
                                facts = new object[] {
                                    new {
                                        name = "Method",
                                        value = "DeploymentQueueCheck"
                                    }, new {
                                        name = "Deployment Id",
                                        value = dict["deploymentId"]
                                    }, new {
                                        name = "Error Message",
                                        value = result
                                    }
                                }.ToList(),
                                markdown = true
                            }
                        }.ToList(),
                    }
                );
```

The issue here is the resulting error message can be very large, and the card produced in Teams is not wrapping the text, it is just letting it trail off the card so a good chunk is just not visible and you can't scroll or see it in any way...

I am not having incredible luck finding any resources on text being cut off in MS teams cards... Is there some way to make the card scrollable? Or make it actually wrap?

Image:
[image]

The above image shows the cutoff. This is from trying to dump out JSON for debugging purposes. In this case we'd have to do some `replace(',', ' ,')` on every message we try to send out. But another problem is a long file path does this too, like `C:\Users\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder`, That has no comma to separate on so it won't wrap.

Comment: I tried to repro your scenario by sending dummy paload with lot of text to incoming webhook but I could not see any issue with truncation. Text is getting wrapeed properly and I see "See More" button on card. Here is the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBiUi.png

Could you please share screenshot and some dummy playload for repro?

Comment: Hmmm so I guess my problem is the error is JSON without spaces between the commas. So I'll probably have to do a replace on the error string to add spaces to get wrapping to work.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: Not entirely, getting some kind of scroll would be nice. Spacing it doesn't entirely solve the problem because a path name can appear in an error message that could be long and it still gets cut off because there wouldn't be a space in there. But doubtful that a scroll bar can be implemented.

Comment: Could you please add the screenshot of the issue?

Comment: I added a screenshot of what I am seeing to my question @Wajeed-MSFT

Answer (score 1):

Yes the issue is with spaces and I didn't find any property to wrap the text in facts.

So I tried sending Adaptive card and that works for me. It is little complicated but works totally fine. I choose Adaptive card because the `TextBlock` have the property to wrap the text. Here is the JSON body.

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "summary": "Error",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
      "content": {
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.2",
        "msteams": {
          "width": "Full"
        },
        "body": [
          {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
              {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": "auto",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Method",
                    "weight": "bolder"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Deployment Id",
                    "weight": "bolder"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Error Message",
                    "weight": "bolder"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "type": "Column",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "DeploymentQueueCheck"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "SomeText"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "ErrorMessageWithNoSpaces.ErrorMessageWithNoSpaces.ErrorMessageWithNoSpaces.ErrorMessageWithNoSpaces.ErrorMessageWithNoSpaces.ErrorMessageWithNoSpaces.ErrorMessageWithNoSpaces.ErrorMessageWithNoSpaces.ErrorMessageWithNoSpaces.ErrorMessageWithNoSpaces.ErrorMessageWithNoSpaces.ErrorMessageWithNoSpaces.ErrorMessageWithNoSpaces.ErrorMessageWithNoSpaces.ErrorMessageWithNoSpaces.ErrorMessageWithNoSpaces.",
                    "wrap": "true"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Output:
[image]